# bash script to check network interface

Tags: bash, shell, system

I want to write a shell script to check a file on Linux and notify me if the file has been modified or changed.

For example: if `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` has been changed, the script should notify me.

This is my code and it doesn't work, please help me:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
   #ATIME=`stat -c %Z /:path/to/the/file.txt`
   #lmodiff= `stat -c %y /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 | sed 's/^\([0-9\-]*\).*/\1/'`
   lmd="2014-09-15"

   cmd=`stat -c %y /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 | sed 's/^\([0-9\-]*\).*/\1/'`
   if [[ "$lmd" != "$cmd" ]]
   then
       echo "RUN COMMNAD"
       #LTIME=$ATIME
   else
        echo "equal"
   fi
done
```

Can you help me to improve my code?

Comment: Or any of the other *sum tools of which there are many (cf. `sha256sum`, `sha512sum`, `md5sum`, etc.).

Comment: We'll need more info than "this code doesn't work".  What is it doing/not doing?  What debugging have you tried so far?

Comment: If the file isn't large one could even just use `diff` for this with a copy of the file taken each time it changes. Or, where available, something like `inotify`.

Comment: @Mr.Llama i want to know if user change his ip, and if hi does change his ip system will "shutdown"

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SLEEP=5
FILE=/path/to/file

SUM=$( md5sum $FILE )
while : ; do
    sleep $SLEEP
    NEWSUM=$( md5sum $FILE )
    if [ "$SUM" != "$NEWSUM" ]; then
        echo "RUN COMMAND"
        SUM=$NEWSUM
    else
        echo "equal"
    fi
done
```

Comment: i want to wirte this script to know that, if user change his ip , and after that , system will `shutdown` but its only echo= 'equal'  , can you help me ?

Comment: Where it says `echo "RUN COMMAND"`, replace that with a `shutdown` command. I would read the `man` page on shutdown for which arguments you want to use, but `shutdown -P now` should power it off after shutdown, whereas `shutdown -r now` will reboot it.